# arrays of arrays in cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

How can one declare an array of arrays in cython?

More precisely, I want to construct (declare and then initialize) an m by n matrix, call it A, in which each entry [i,j] is a 1-dimensional array of doubles (of length `min(i,j)`, filled with zeros) of the form

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] A[i,j]
A[i,j] = np.zeros((min(i,j)), dtype=np.double)
```

For (m,n)=(4,3), `print A` should return something like this:

```
[[[], [], []],
[[], [0.], [0.]],
[[], [0.], [0.,0.]],
[[], [0.], [0.,0.]]]
```

How do I declare and initialize A?

Comment: Where are those 0s coming from?

Comment: @Veedrac: that's how I want to initialize the matrix. Element [i,j] has in it an array of zeros of size min(i,j).

Comment: Your two dimensional array will have to be of dtype `object`, not double. I don't have a clue how you tell cython that, though. You are going to have a serious performance penalty by having an array of `object` type, since accessing an element is going to involve dealing with Python objects: are you sure that cython is going to significantly speed up your code?

Comment: @danb If you're OK with having the 2D array type `object`, this is easy. If not you're going to have to have some sort of indirection that'll probably leave you working with C types. Which do you want?

Comment: @Veedrac: both please. I need to test to see the price in speed I pay for the slower version.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with those arrays? Why do you want to `cdef` `A`? You can get the above working in Python as: `m, n = 4, 3; A = np.empty((m, n), dtype=np.object); for i in xrange(m):; for j in xrange(n):; A[i, j] = np.zeros(np.minimum(i, j))` You can `cdef` `i` and `j` to shave a fraction of performance, but the data structure you have in mind is very likely not going to be very performing...

Answer (score 7):

The object method:

```
import numpy

def thing(int m, int n):
    cdef int i, j
    cdef object[:, :] A = numpy.empty((m, n), dtype=object)

    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            A[i, j] = numpy.zeros(min(i, j))

    return A
```

Note that that `object[:, :]` syntax is the newer version, the `numpy.ndarray[object, ndim=2]` version is deprecated. The newer version is GIL-free (well, probably not when using `object` types), normally faster (never slower), type-agnostic (works on anything supporting `memoryview`) and cleaner.

If you want to iterate over the sub-arrays, you'd be doing:

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        subarray = A[i, j]
        for k in range(subarray.size):
            ...
```

and you can either type `subarray` to `object` (best for small `subarray`s) or `float[:]` (best for large `subarray`s).

---

The C-level solution is proving to be very tricky. I have a feeling you'll basically end up writing it with pure-C types.

So I'm abandoning that, and here's what I'd do:

```
import numpy

def thing(int m, int n):
    cdef int i, j

    cdef float[:, :, :] A = numpy.zeros((m, n, min(m, n)), dtype=float)
    cdef int[:, :] A_lengths = numpy.empty((m, n), dtype=int)

    for i in range(A_lengths.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A_lengths.shape[1]):
            A_lengths[i, j] = min(i, j)

    return A, A_lengths
```

Basically, make a 3D array and a 2D array of corresponding lengths. If there is only a linear variation in lengths (so the max length is a reasonable factor [I'd say up to about 10] of the mean length) then this should have acceptable overhead. It'll allow pure-C calculations while having a tasty memoryview interface.

---

That's all I've got. Take it or leave it.